# Using jQuery in MySQL php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new to using Jquery using mysql and PHP.
I am using the following code to pull the data. But there is not data or error displayed.

JQUERY:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function doAjaxPost() {
      // get the form values
      var field_a = $("#field_a").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "serverscript.php",
        data: "ID="+field_a,
        success: function(resp){
          $("#resposnse").html(resp);
        },
        error: function(e){
          alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="field_a">
    <option value="data_1">data_1</option>
    <option value="data_2">data_2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Ajax Request" onClick="doAjaxPost()">
  <a href="#" onClick="doAjaxPost()">Here</a>
  <div id="resposnse">
  </div>
</body>
```

and now `serverscript.php`

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['ID'])) {
    $nm = $_POST['ID'];
    echo $nm;
    //insert your code here for the display.
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pop") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("JPro") or die(mysql_error());
    $result1 = mysql_query("select Name from results where ID = \"$nm\" ")
                 or die(mysql_error());  

    // store the record of the "example" table into $row
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 )) {
      $tc = $row1['Name'];
      echo $tc;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have a closing form tag `</form>` that you do not open, while you open `<input type="button"` but don't close it and your `<img src="ajax-loader.gif"` is not closed either...

Comment: edited. there is a gt symbol in the button tag, right?

Comment: Yes, you have a `>`, but you either need a `/>` or a `</input>` to make it valid html (guess it's not related to your problem but you might want to give it a try). I reformatted your code btw.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell me the problem with my code, not displaying the results.

Comment: By the way , I am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head section

Comment: @JPro: I don't know what the problem with your code is, but formatting it properly will help those who do know.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mike said, this also worked for me when I put it in the ready function and removed the button onclick. Open up your error console in Firefox and see if it is outputting anything

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ID'])){
  echo ($_POST['ID']);
  exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title> Heather Alexandra </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../intranet/include/js/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ajax").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test.php",
          data: "ID="+$("#field_a").val(),
          success: function(resp){
            $("#resposnse").html(resp);
          },
          error: function(e){
            alert('Error: ' + e);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 822px;">
  <select id="field_a">
    <option value="data_1">data_1</option>
    <option value="data_2">data_2</option>
  </select>
  <input id="ajax" type="button" value="Ajax Request">
  <div id="resposnse"></div>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did everything you did except changed the serverscript.php to:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['ID'])) {
    $nm = $_POST['ID'];
    echo $nm;

    }
?>
```

And the script worked fine. I think all you have to do is get back down to the basics and find out what is actually generating the error. Try using firebug for firefox to see if you are generating any script errors. If not try changing the serverscript.php to use $_GET and type the following address to see what you get: http://yourtestserver/serverscript.php?ID=data_1

Debugging can get tricky when you deal with ajax but if you break it down to it's individual pieces it should make it easier.